# How to get identifier name of a specific control in SWIFT 3 (Created through storyboard) to set values from DB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield, swift3

I have created like a 100+ controls (labels, textboxes, imageviews), using the storyboard (yes I was that patient :( or are there any easier ways to do this lol) for a certain chart and now my problem is how to iterate through the controls using its identifier name (which I did manually by ctrl + draging to the swift file). Is there any way to get its 'identifier name' (like in Android) so I can set values for that specific control w/ the values from my database. E.g:

```
for i in 0 ..< chartDetails.count{

    for view in self.innerView.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let txtFld = view as? UITextField{

            if(txtFld.identifier == "TXT_L_" + String((i + 1)))
            {
               txtFld.text = chartDetails[i].ConValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other solutions said to use the tag, but I don't think it would work in this scenario.

I tried this but got an error, 'unwrapping optional value'

```
for i in 0 ..< chartDetails.count{

    for view in self.innerView.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let txtFld = view as? UITextField{

            if let value = txt as? UIAccessibilityIdentification{
                print("Test: " + value.accessibilityIdentifier!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks to alexburtnik, in order for you to set values in the controls you created, you need to set accessibility of each control programmatically.

[image]

Comment: If those controls and labels are similar to each other, you should better use `IBOutletCollection` (or rather several of them) and then iterate through the objects in that array.

Comment: Uhh so I have to destroy the 100+ connections I've made lol, Though could you put that as the answer and provide how exactly to iterate on that collection and get its "identifier"? Thank you! @alexburtnik

Comment: What do you mean by `identifier`? Are you talking `accessibilityIdentifier`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those controls and labels are similar to each other, you should use a `IBOutletCollection` for each group instead of individual `IBOutlet`s.
In order to do this just select `IBOutletCollection` when you *ctrl & drag* the first element in a group to your class. You should see something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
```

All subsequent elements of a group you just drag to the same variable and they will be added to the array in runtime.

Now you can iterate over those elements just as you do with any other array:

```
for textField in textFields {
    if let identifier = textField.accessibilityIdentifier {
        print("Test: " + identifier)
    }
}
```

Note, that I print only if `accessibilityIdentifier` exists, so it won't crash as your code. In fact you should avoid forced unwrapping (`!`) almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! will try accessibilityIdentifier

Comment: Hi, I have tried the IBOutletCollection, however how can I add an Identifier to each textfield? Like txtfield1, txtfield2, and so on because it wont go to the if let identifier statement

Comment: apparently I had to equate each control for its accessibilityIdentifier to make it work. Thank you so much! I can now finally manipulate my chart haha